# importing data into mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql

i have created an html form with input type="file" and now i m uploading a text file with php and file is moving into specific folder so every thing is going well with a successful connection to db.
But i want to import that file's data in to mysql databse and that thing is not working 
the script is :

```
<?php
$sql32="load data local infile 'C:\\wamp\\www\\my\\db_import\\$fname' 
into table  contact_list (name, address, dob, reminder, phone, mobile, email)" ;
$sql33=mysql_query($sql32) or die("could not upload data");
//here $fname is the file name
?>
```

if i run this query(replacing, $fname, variable with the file name) direct into  wamp server phpmyadmin it is runnig and data is being imported . 
but via php script as the stated above is not working and giving die msg "could not upload data"..
so whats wrong ? please suggest me..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think may be your error with file path. try once i am not sure..

```
'C:\\wamp\\www\\my\\db_import\\$fname'
```

change to

'my/db_import/$fname'

check [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you established connection? Maybe your code doesn't work because you cannot connect to your database server. Or else your full script. Because my script is mysql_query($con,$sqln)
Sorry If i was wrong, I'm new.
Poom

Comment: yes, as i said that every this is working fine but that thing is not working   :(

Comment: The kind of scenario you are talking about often happens when you haven't established a connection with the database. Maybe you forgot to include the connection file? give it a check please or else plz post the complete php script that you are using for this in the script i can see here i dont see you establishing a database connection anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$fname` contains a value? Maybe try echoing it out.

Also, I always have trouble with variables in strings like that, try wrapping it in curly braces as such:

```
<?php
$sql32="load data local infile 'C:\\wamp\\www\\my\\db_import\\{$fname}' 
into table  contact_list (name, address, dob, reminder, phone, mobile, email)" ;
$sql33=mysql_query($sql32) or die("could not upload data");
//here $fname is the file name
?>
```